# Blob.encode[lamports] requires (length 8) Uint8Array as src while making transfer

Tags: web3.js

My code is

```
    let transaction = new Transaction().add(
    error line --> SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: senderWallet.publicKey,
        toPubkey: to,
        lamports: (LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * amount)
      })
    );

    let signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
      senderWallet,
    ])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, its difficult to tell what might be causing the error you're seeing.

However, here is a code snippet you can reference for creating a transaction with a single Sol transfer instruction.

```
    // Define the amount to transfer
    const transferAmount = 0.1 // 0.1 SOL

    // Create a transfer instruction for transferring SOL from wallet_1 to wallet_2
    const transferInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: wallet_1.publicKey,
      toPubkey: wallet_2.publicKey,
      lamports: transferAmount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, // Convert transferAmount to lamports
    })

    // Add the transfer instruction to a new transaction
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(transferInstruction)

    // Attempt to send and confirm the transaction
    try {
      await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [wallet_1])
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Transaction unsuccessful: ", error)
    }
```